# Accessing listener method parameter from another method

Tags: java, concurrency, listener

I am trying to do the following. I have a method `foo()` and from that method I call method `doSomeWork()`. I also have a listener `MytListener` that listens to `doSomeWork()` and calls method `onExecution()` when `doSomeWork()` is complete.

```
public void foo() {
    doSomeWork();
    // wait until doSomeWork is complete
    // access output from method onExecution
    // do some actions with output
}

public class MyListener implements Listener {
    void onExecution(Output output) {}
}
```

My goal is to wait until method `doSomeWork` is complete and then access `output` from inside method `foo`. Is it really possible to achieve that and could you provide some advice on how it can be done?

Comment: So is foo() in a different class from MyListener?

Comment: That's a weird flow of logic. Why not  on `MyListener` call  a method on whatever class `foo()` is and do there *some actions with output*?

Comment: @FailingCoder Not necessary, foo() can be inside MyListener class.

Comment: @Augusto Object Output will be created only when listener method onExecution is called. I can do some actions with output from inside onExecution method only. Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a Listener class. All you need to do is this:

```
public void foo(){
    doSomeWork();
    onExecution(null); // This method will only execute AFTER doSomeWork has been completed
}
void onExecution(Output output) {}
```

Comment: But where did that 'value' come from? In my case onExecution is inside listener and when it's called, I have non-null object Output.

Comment: `value` is whatever value you want it to be

Comment: Let me clarify. I have a third-party library listener with method onExecute, and when that method is called, it already has created non-null Output object.